# If a question is posted to one site and receives answers, can it be changed to a different site?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover

If a question is posted to one Stack Exchange site and receives answers, can it still be changed to another Stack Exchange site? If yes, how? It can't be deleted now that it has an answer.

I want to change [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13119/why-dont-switches-always-flood) to superuser as I think it would receive better answers there. It's hard to take a site seriously when answers like "Short answer - Flooding doesn't scale." get +3 votes. Though this isn't the only problem.

Comment: A moderator can definitely migrate (I've had upvoted answers on questions that were later migrated) so you could try flagging, but I think if it's on-topic on the original site they normally hesitate to migrate, maybe even more so on a beta where they're after all the questions they can get.

Comment: To be honest, your comment doesn't help much either in improving the quality of that community...

Comment: @rene a answer such as "it doesn't scale" shouldn't even require a comment. But thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag it and request for migration.

If it is not too old ( < 60 days ), and as long as the community/mods agree it is off topic where it is, then it can be migrated.

If it is on-topic, but you think it hasn't got sufficient attention you can always raise a bounty.

Comment: How will I know if it's being considered for migration? We don't have a PM system so we can't really talk.

Comment: @Celeritas Generally a mod will comment on it when it gets migrated, or else the mod would probably decline your flag and optionally leave a comment, which could view on your flag history page (accessible via your profile).

Answer (score 4):

> If a question is posted to one Stack Exchange site and receives answers, can it still be changed to another Stack Exchange site? If yes, how? It can't be deleted now that it has an answer.

As Rory already mentioned, it can be migrated; however, normally we do that only if the question is off-topic.  That said, I'm a mod for the site (and answered your question); I will personally perform the migration if that's what is required.  However, I'm not convinced yet :-)

> I want to change this question to superuser as I think it would receive better answers there. It's hard to take a site seriously when answers like "Short answer - Flooding doesn't scale." get +3 votes.

Flagging for migration is a non-sequitur to the complaint of "I don't like that answer getting so many votes"; if it bothers you that badly, you should ask for clarification in comments.

The core issue seems to be that you downvoted a short answer, and your downvote was followed by three upvotes.  The same thing has happened to me hundreds of times on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), [SF](https://serverfault.com/) and [SU](https://superuser.com/); it's annoying, but changing sites won't change that reality.  Votes are personal decisions; you simply can't control how other people vote.

Furthermore, your comment [didn't even attempt to clarify the answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13119/why-dont-switches-always-flood#comment20126_13120).  You could have asked, "what specifically doesn't scale?", and I'd bet you would have gotten a satisfactory explanation.  If your complaint is *"I can't take the Network Engineering site seriously when that answer got three votes"*, my response is *"I can't take your flag seriously until you actually try to resolve the problem"*.

We aim to please, but let's be reasonable.  Before I migrate [your question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13119/why-dont-switches-always-flood) to another site, please take the time to ask nicely for clarification, instead of leaving a comment like `short answer = -1`.

Comment: Actually there are other problems than upvotes to a question that is poor. It almost seems the direction the question is heading in is not a good fit for the stackexchange. For example "You're arguing...I'm arguing..." this isn't a debate, I just want the facts. Also your own answer seems a little bit open ended: for example you say that switches are more secure, but I seriously doubt that people choose a switch over a hub because they want security, security would be built at a different level. Also it would be nice if the answers didn't use too much jargon, for example what is "linerate"?

Comment: This is not the place to ask for clarification on a Network Engineering answer.  I will edit [my answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/13126/775) to address what you've asked about

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me know when the edit is done.

Comment: @Celeritas: done